# How to avoid getting duplicated elements on localstorage array

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage

i have the following code that generates a new element on an array in my localstorage each time i click on a button

```
let addCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('product-description-add')
for (let i = 0; i < addCartItemButtons.length; i++){
    let button = addCartItemButtons[i]
    button.addEventListener('click', function(event){
        let buttonClicked = event.target
        let getTitle = buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('.product-title').innerText
        let getImage = buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('.product-header img').src
        let getColor = buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('.product-description-text li span').innerText
        let getSize = buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('.product-description-text li select').value
        let getPrice = buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('.product-description-price').innerText
        let getSpan = buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('li span').getAttribute('id')
        let oldItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('newProduct')) || [];
        let newItem = {
            'id': i+1,
            'title': getTitle,
            'image': getImage,
            'color': getColor,
            'size': getSize,
            'price': getPrice,
            'spanid': getSpan,
        };
        let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('newProduct'))
        if(localStorage.getItem('newProduct') == null) {
            oldItems.push(newItem);
            localStorage.setItem('newProduct', JSON.stringify(oldItems));
        } else {
            if(data.indexOf(newItem) == -1){
                oldItems.push(newItem);
                localStorage.setItem('newProduct', JSON.stringify(oldItems));
            }else{
                alert('element already added')
            }
        }
    })
}
```

My problem is that I've tried to create a validation to check if the element has already been added to the local storage, so in that case there should appear the alert, but it's not working at all and I'm still being able to add an element to my localstorage after I added it for the first time. I can't get of how to resolve this, any ideas? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks for the help I've received from @traktor, I was able to come up with a solution to this problem. I've added a data-prodid to each product and then pass it as 'id' to localstorage. Then I check if there's any element in my array that contains the same ID i'm clicking into and if there's any result, then an alert gets executed. Otherwise, the element gets saved.

```
let addCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('product-description-add')
for (let i = 0; i < addCartItemButtons.length; i++){
    let button = addCartItemButtons[i]
    button.addEventListener('click', function(event){
        let buttonClicked = event.target
        let getProdId = buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.getAttribute('data-prodid')
        let getTitle = buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('.product-title').innerText
        let getImage = buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('.product-header img').src
        let getColor = buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('.product-description-text li span').innerText
        let getSize = buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('.product-description-text li select').value
        let getPrice = buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('.product-description-price').innerText
        let getSpan = buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('li span').getAttribute('id')
        let oldItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('newProduct')) || [];
        let newItem = {
            'id': getProdId,
            'title': getTitle,
            'image': getImage,
            'color': getColor,
            'size': getSize,
            'price': getPrice,
            'spanid': getSpan,
        };
        
        if(localStorage.getItem('newProduct') == null) {
            oldItems.push(newItem);
            localStorage.setItem('newProduct', JSON.stringify(oldItems));
        } else {
            let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('newProduct'))
            let idCheck = data.filter(x => x.id === newItem.id).map(x => x.foo);
            let idCheckResults = idCheck.length
            if(idCheckResults > 0){
                alert('element already added')
            }else{
                oldItems.push(newItem);
                localStorage.setItem('newProduct', JSON.stringify(oldItems));
            }
        }
        let windowCartProducts = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("newProduct"));
        let productsInCart = document.getElementById('cartProducts')
        let productsAdded = 0
        for(let i = 0; i < windowCartProducts.length; i++){
            productsAdded = windowCartProducts.length
        }
        productsInCart.innerHTML = productsAdded + `<i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>`
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problems are arising because objects do not compare as equal just because they have the same property values.

```
let oldItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('newProduct')) || [];
```

creates `oldItems` as an empty array or an Array of newly created objects with property values representing previous items clicked and saved.

```
let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('newProduct'))
```

will also create an array of new objects for previous buttons clicked, if there were any, but won't contain the same objects as `oldItems` because `JSON.parse` creates new objects each time it is called.

Defining `newItem` also creates a new object which will **not** be the same object as any of the entries in `oldItems` or `data`.

To solve the problem you could add unique product codes to all items, so you can search previous data for a match based on product code alone, or write a comparison routine to check all the properties that need differentiating (such as color).

Personally I would try to get a product-id added into page data, search for it among previous items, and if product-ids match,  then then the item has been been clicked before (but the customer *could* be ordering a different color).

Be wary of using the button loop counter as an `id` value, or even the image source string - it's easy to imagine ways they could go wrong or be compromised by page changes outside your control.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've added a 'data-prodid' to each product and i'm saving it as an element into localstorage each time i click on the button. Any idea of how can i get this to set a function that allows me to avoid getting duplicates?

Comment: The most straight forward approach is to save (as JSON text in localStorage) an object with keys set to the `prod-id` of items clicked with property value the `newItem` value from when the button was originally clicked. This will make it inherently impossible to have two items with the same product id in storage.